# Chrome Extension - execute script not injecting in new tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I can't get execute script to work. I followed the example and can't get anything to execute. I have tried editing the permissions and I have tried injecting a console.log, a settimeout. I have read the documentation repeatedly, I am at a loss. I am simply trying to inject a script that enters in a username and password and then click the login button.

```
var script =  ' var e = document.getElementById("email"); var p = document.getElementById("password");'+
              'e.value ="'+currentEmployee.email+'"; p.value = "'+currentEmployee.password+'";'+
              'var osbut = document.getElementById("osLoginButton"); osbut.submit();';
chrome.tabs.create({
    url: 'https://www.example.net/login'
}, function (tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
        code: script
    });
});
```

Here is my manifest.json

```
{
   "name": "Example",
  "description": "example",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_script": "popup.js",
        "default_title": "example!"
},
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage", 
    "http://*/",
    "https://*/",
    "tabs",
    "*://www.example.net/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: If that site dynamically creates its page contents, you need to wait for it to complete in the injected code. For example, add setTimeout or MutationObserver.

Comment: I did a setTimeout and wrapped the script in an anonymous function. Still no luck, var script =  'setTimeout(function(){var e = document.getElementById("email"); var p = document.getElementById("password");'+
              'e.value ="'+currentEmployee.email+'"; p.value = "'+currentEmployee.password+'";'+
              'var osbut = document.getElementById("osLoginButton"); osbut.submit()}, 3000)';  Nothing, can you look at my permissions are they right? And this is running on the popup, not a background js would that make a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I finally got to work. The biggest thing I needed was that the tab needed to not be active. Thats what was screwing everything up. The newly created tab stopped the popup from continuing with the functions. So the new tab was created and even though there was a callback the popup was destroyed so there was nothing to callback to. Hopefully this helps someone else, using a popup.js with newly created tabs.

```
chrome.tabs.create({
    url: web, active: false
}, function (tab) {myTab = tab; 
  setTimeout(checkLoad, 2000);
  }
)
}//end func

function checkLoad(){ console.log(web);
chrome.tabs.query({status: "complete", url: web }, function (tab) {
  console.log(tab);
  for(var i = 0; i < tab.length; i++){ if(tab[i].title =! undefined){setTimeout(pressure, 1000)}
else{setTimeout(checkLoad, 1000) }

}} )}

function pressure(){

var script = "var e = ''; var p = ''; var j = '';"+
'setTimeout(function(){'+
'var l = document.getElementsByTagName("input");'+
'console.log(l);for(var i = 0; i < l.length; i++){if (l[i].type == "email" || l[i].name == "email" || l[i].id == "email" || l[i].id.includes("user") ){ e = l[i]; console.log(e.name)};if (l[i].type == "password" || l[i].id == "password" ||  l[i].id.includes("pass") || l[i].name.includes("pass")){ p = l[i]; console.log(p.name)};if (l[i].type == "submit"){ j = l[i]; j.click(); }};'+
'e.focus();'+'e.value ="";'+
'e = document.execCommand("insertText", true,'+ '"'+currentEmployee.email+'");'+
'p.value = "";'+
'p.focus();'+
'p = document.execCommand("insertText", true, '+'"'+currentEmployee.password+'");'+
'}, 750);'+
'setTimeout(function(){j.click()}, 1000)';
 chrome.tabs.executeScript(myTab.id, {allFrames : true, code : script})
}
```

Comment: Thanks you saved my day ! Just a comment, in checkLoad if your query is empty, the function will stop directly, you should set a variable to true if you find something and recall checkLoad only if the variable is false.